# Group Rows By Column Header and a Reference Column / Cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, zapier

I am a total Noob at this and have I am trying my best to learn but I guess wrong questions in Google means wrong tutorial which makes my learning curve harder and slower, anyway I need help with this situation

I have a Spreadsheet that I need to work on like this:
Here is the link to the Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfbSbUvwFFNSACVL-UpDnX0qzVxehY6rXVzco_0IY6E/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the Screenshot of the table:

https://www.screencast.com/t/H0uRQdjsBTxz
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlkJ5.png

So what I wanted to do is to Check Col2 [B] and make it a reference all of the rows that has the same Order No Will then be stacked with the Corresponding Column Header or A Custom Text and should appear like Col12 [L] So for the number of Rows it should show all of the orders as so. I hope I was able to explain it and I hope that you guys can help me out.

I need to do it either in Python or as Javascript with JSON support since it needs to be used in Zapier as an automation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code to see what you' ve tried so far and to see what isnt working

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Rmaxx I don't have a code yet I am still trying to research that as well. That's why I ended up here in this forum/site. I thought this is an area where I can ask for help.